# Testing Configure method for added middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, xunit

I'm having issues writing an xunit for the Configure method in Startup.cs.

Basically all I want to do is call that method and check that all required middlewares are in that method. This isn't an unit test v integration test question, just literally how can I construct IApplicationBuilder, IHostingEnvironment and then check mvc has been added for example.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you are trying to test that the framework does what it was designed to do. That would have been tested by its designers already.

Either way, mocks of those interfaces can be created, manually or via mocking framework, and used to test the subject method, but that would also require internal knowledge of the members used by the add middleware extensions, assuming it is a custom extension.

Comment: No, I'm trying to test that no one removes a vital middleware component. I'm not trying to test the mechanism of adding middleware.